# Aperture value appears as '- -' in Olympus E410

Tags: aperture, manual-focus, lens-mount, four-thirds

I have just started using manual focus and prime lenses with my Olympus E410 (four-thirds).

Intermittently, the aperture value is invisible, both through the viewfinder and in the LCD display. Instead of an f stop, the aperture appears as two dashes: "- -".

When this fault occurs, I cannot adjust the aperture with auto-focus Olympus lenses, and manually-focused shots appear blurred, even if I adjust the aperture on the manual focus lens itself.

Do you have any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you have a lens with manual diaphragm ring.

Your camera will be able to adjust it only if you close it to maximum.

In other words, if you want your camera to be able to change aperture, you need to fully close the aperture manually.